# How do I understand WPF binding?  DisplayMemberBinding vs DataTemplate GridView Binding?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I am very confused with binding in WPF.  For example, binding with a ListView can be done by  **DisplayMemberBinding** but can also be done by using **DataTemplate in grid view**.

When do I use one approach over the other?

Can someone please suggest how to understand binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataTemplates` allow for complex structures possibly showing *various members*, `DisplayMemberBinding` just displays *one member* of the object. That's about it, read about data binding [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). Also see the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `DisplayMemberBinding` a `Textblock` is used.  If you need to use another UI element then you need to use a `DataTemplate`.

From the documentation
[GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding.aspx)

The following properties are all used to define the content and style of a column cell, and are listed here in their order of precedence, from highest to lowest:

DisplayMemberBinding

CellTemplate

CellTemplateSelector

Comment: Are you sure about that? I would assume it only does that for strings.

Comment: It calls `ToString()` on other types to get them into a `string` - `DisplayMemberPath` will only show one member, and will only show it as a `string`. As Blam says, if you need to use another UI element then you need to use a `DataTemplate`

Comment: @H.B. To my knowledge Gridview does not have the various column types like a DataGrid.

Comment: @Blam: What i meant was that it might as well throw that member in a `ContentPresenter` and "see what happens", if there is a `DataTemplate` associated with the type of property that could be used implicitly. Strings then would just display in a TextBlock.

Comment: @H.B. I can only comment on my experience and not what it could do.  My experience is that Gridview does not honor external templates.  Maybe I am doing it wrong.